# Extract zlib compressed data from binary file in python

Tags: language-agnostic, zlib, binaryfiles, compression

My company uses a legacy file format for Electromiography data, which is no longer in production. However, there is some interest in maintaining retro-compatibility, so I am studying the possibility to write a reader for that file format.

By analyzing a very convoluted former source code written in Delphi, the file reader/writer uses ZLIB, and inside a HexEditor it looks like there is a file header in binary ASCII (with fields like "Player", "Analyzer" readily readable), followed by a compressed string containing raw data.

My doubt is: how should I proceed in order to identify:

- If it is a compressed stream;
- Where does the compressed stream start and where does it end;

From Wikipedia:

> zlib compressed data is typically written with a gzip or a zlib
>   wrapper. The wrapper encapsulates the raw DEFLATE data by adding a
>   header and trailer. This provides stream identification and error
>   detection

Is this relevant?

I'll be glad to post more information, but I don't know what would be most relevant.

Thanks for any hint.

EDIT: I have the working application, and can use it to record actual data of any time length, getting files even smaller than 1kB if necessary.

---

Some sample files:

A freshly created one, without datastream: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/4849855/Mio_File/HeltonEmpty.mio

The same as above after a very short (1 second?) datastream has been saved: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/4849855/Mio_File/HeltonFilled.mio

A different one, from a patient named "manco" instead of "Helton", with an even shorter stream (ideal for Hex viewing): https://dl.dropbox.com/u/4849855/Mio_File/manco_short.mio

Instructions: each file should be the file of a patient (a person). Inside these files, one or more exams are saved, each exam consisting of one or more time series. The provided files contain only one exam, with one data series.

Comment: Am I understanding your question right: You have no proper specification of the file format and want to know about reverse engineering techniques to identify the file format's structure and layout?

Comment: @LukasGraf Don't look too hard on me, but the answer is... Yep! It's pretty much a last effort of our company with this file format, but any progress would be important to us.

Comment: Ok, just wanted so make sure I understand the question correctly. I didn't mean to sound judgmental :) But Python then probably only applies as the language for implementation, once you're done reverse engineering the file format (which will probably take a lot more time than the implementation itself).

Comment: You're right. Gonna remove the tag.

Comment: Can you upload such a 1kB file somewhere and paste a link in your question? I'll see if I can come up with an general purpose answer, but of course it's much easier if there's a sample to tinker with.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To start, why not scan the files for all valid zip streams (it's good enough for small files and to figure out the format):

```
import zlib
from glob import glob

def zipstreams(filename):
    """Return all zip streams and their positions in file."""
    with open(filename, 'rb') as fh:
        data = fh.read()
    i = 0
    while i < len(data):
        try:
            zo = zlib.decompressobj()
            yield i, zo.decompress(data[i:])
            i += len(data[i:]) - len(zo.unused_data)
        except zlib.error:
            i += 1

for filename in glob('*.mio'):
    print(filename)
    for i, data in zipstreams(filename):
        print (i, len(data))
```

Looks like the data streams contain little-endian double precision floating point data:

```
import numpy
from matplotlib import pyplot

for filename in glob('*.mio'):
    for i, data in zipstreams(filename):
        if data:
            a = numpy.fromstring(data, '<f8')
            pyplot.plot(a[1:])
            pyplot.title(filename + ' - %i' % i)
            pyplot.show()
```

Comment: I am amazed, I have no words. It JUST PLAIN WORKED! Of course I'll have to study the subtleties tomorrow (at home now), but I'll come back to comment some key points so others might benefit. Thank you VERY much for you time and interest!

Answer (score 8):

zlib is a thin wrapper around data compressed with the
[DEFLATE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deflate) algorithm and is defined in [RFC1950](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1950#page-4):

> ```
>   A zlib stream has the following structure:
>
>        0   1
>      +---+---+
>      |CMF|FLG|   (more-->)
>      +---+---+
>
>   (if FLG.FDICT set)
>
>        0   1   2   3
>      +---+---+---+---+
>      |     DICTID    |   (more-->)
>      +---+---+---+---+
>
>      +=====================+---+---+---+---+
>      |...compressed data...|    ADLER32    |
>      +=====================+---+---+---+---+
> ```

So it adds at least two, possibly six bytes before and 4 bytes with an
[ADLER32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adler-32) checksum after the raw DEFLATE compressed data.

The first byte contains the **CMF** (Compression Method and flags), which is split
into **CM** (Compression method) (first 4 bits) and **CINFO** (Compression info) (last
4 bits).

From this it's quite clear that unfortunately already the first two bytes
of a zlib stream can vary a lot depending on what compression method and
settings have been used.

Luckily, I stumbled upon a post by Mark Adler, the author of the ADLER32
algorithm, where he [lists the most common and less common combinations of those
two starting bytes](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.compression/msg/f1d83521ee85a348).

With that out of the way, let's look at how we can use Python to examine zlib:

```py
>>> import zlib
>>> msg = 'foo'
>>> [hex(ord(b)) for b in zlib.compress(msg)]
['0x78', '0x9c', '0x4b', '0xcb', '0xcf', '0x7', '0x0', '0x2', '0x82', '0x1', '0x45']
```

So the zlib data created by Python's `zlib` module (using default options) starts with
**`78 9c`**. We'll use that to create a script that writes a custom file format
cointaining a preamble, some zlib compressed data and a footer.

We then write a second script that scans a file for that two byte pattern,
starts decompressing everything that follows as a zlib stream and figures out
where the stream ends and the footer starts.

**create.py**

```py
import zlib

msg = 'foo'
filename = 'foo.compressed'

compressed_msg = zlib.compress(msg)
data = 'HEADER' + compressed_msg + 'FOOTER'

with open(filename, 'wb') as outfile:
    outfile.write(data)
```

Here we take `msg`, compress it with zlib, and surround it with a header and
footer before we write it out to a file.

Header and footer are of fixed length in this example, but they could of course
have arbitrary, unknown lengths.

Now for the script that tries to find a zlib stream in such a file. Because for
this example we know exactly what marker to expect I'm using only one, but
obviously the list `ZLIB_MARKERS` could be filled with all the markers from the
post mentioned above.

**ident.py**

```py
import zlib

ZLIB_MARKERS = ['\x78\x9c']
filename = 'foo.compressed'

infile = open(filename, 'r')
data = infile.read()

pos = 0
found = False

while not found:
    window = data[pos:pos+2]
    for marker in ZLIB_MARKERS:
        if window == marker:
            found = True
            start = pos
            print "Start of zlib stream found at byte %s" % pos
            break
    if pos == len(data):
        break
    pos += 1

if found:
    header = data[:start]

    rest_of_data = data[start:]
    decomp_obj = zlib.decompressobj()
    uncompressed_msg = decomp_obj.decompress(rest_of_data)

    footer = decomp_obj.unused_data

    print "Header: %s" % header
    print "Message: %s" % uncompressed_msg
    print "Footer: %s" % footer

if not found:
    print "Sorry, no zlib streams starting with any of the markers found."
```

The idea is this:

- Start at the beginning of the file and create a two byte search
  window.
- Move the search window forward in one-byte increments.
- For every window check if it matches any of the two byte markers we
  defined.
- If a match is found, record the starting position, stop searching and
  try to decompress everything that follows.

Now, finding the end of the stream isn't as trivial as looking for two marker
bytes. zlib streams are neither terminated by a fixed byte sequence nor is
their length indicated in any of the header fields. Instead it's terminated by
a four byte ADLER32 checksum that must match the data up to this point.

The way it works is that the internal C function `inflate()` continously keeps
trying to decompress the stream as it reads it, and if it comes across a
matching checksum, signals that to its caller, indicating that the rest of the
data isn't part of the zlib stream anymore.

In Python this behavior is exposed when using decompression objects instead of simply
calling `zlib.decompress()`. Calling `decompress(string)` on a `Decompress` object
will decompress a zlib stream in `string` and return the decompressed data that was part of the stream. Everything that follows the stream will be stored in `unused_data` and can be
retrieved afterwards.

This should produce the following output on a file created with the first
script:

```
Start of zlib stream found at byte 6
Header: HEADER
Message: foo
Footer: FOOTER
```

The example can easily be modified to write the uncompressed message to a file
instead of printing it. Then you can further analyze the formerly zlib
compressed data, and try to identify known fields in the metadata in the
header and footer you separated out.

Comment: The explanation you provided is very enlightening, and I plan to read it thoroughly. In the end, cgohlke provided a somewhat bruteforce that worked for my small-sized files, but I think I'll have to look for the two byte header like you suggested. As soon as I get some good results I come back, thank you very much for your time and interest!

Comment: Excellent! I think even though my answer may provide some educational value about the details and background of the problem, the solution offered by @cgohlke is much more elegant than mine. It accounts for multiple streams per file and doesn't rely on a two byte marker. If you can let zlib do that work for you that's easier and probably more reliable than doing it yourself.

Comment: I appreciate your comprehension. Actually, I've chosen his answer because he thrown the right plotted results right at my face with a bunch of code lines, even though I don't plan to use brute-force on the bigger files, but instead to use your header bytes to look for the beginning of the streams the right way. Thanks again!